# Running total using sum over

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an AccountEntry table which looks as follows (including the balance computed column im trying to achieve):

| id | PeriodId | Date | Value | FixedValue | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-02 | 120 | 0 | 120 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-11-04 | 60 | 0 | 60 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-02-01 | 0 | 60 | 60 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-02-05 | -200 | 0 | -140 |

The third row can be mainly disregarded in the above example, it was just to show the reason for my AccountPeriodId in the script, which we use to group different vacation years etc.

We use this table to add to our HR systems various accounts (flex, vacation, time off in lieu etc.)

We used to persist the current balance on each of the entries, but stopped doing that as many errors followed with that and now only persist the different transactions.

However...
Often we do need to show the running total of the balance of an accountentry and I figured I could use a computed column in conjunction with a UDF to accomplish that, and I created this  function:

```sql
create function dbo.UDF_GetAggregateBalance (@id int)
returns
int as
begin
    declare @b int;
    with result_CTE (id, balance) 
    as
    (
        SELECT
        id,
        SUM(e.value) 
          OVER (partition by e.accountperiodid ORDER BY e.useddate desc rows between current 
          row and unbounded following) balance
        FROM accountentry e
    )
    select @b=balance from result_CTE where id = @id    
    
    return (@b)

end

alter table accountentry add Balance as dbo.UDF_GetAggregateBalance(id)
```

which works fine... The caveat comes with the field "fixedValue" is meant as a "reset", meaning an entry with a "fixedValue" will always have exactly the balance of the fixed value, and later entries will be in relation to this fixed value.

In my example table above this would mean that the balance of entry 5 should be -140 as the entry before had a fixed value of 60 and we spent 200 minutes after that

Is this possible in any way to do in sql? The issue in doing it in our application code is just that well always need to load the entire account history to show correct balances for each entry.

Comment: *"Often we do need to show the running total of the balance of an accountentry and I figured I could use a computed column in conjunction with a UDF to accomplish that"* I would suggest against that. You would be better off using a `VIEW`.

Comment: Might be a better idea, I will consider that - my question still stands though :)

Comment: So, for your sample data, what are your expected results?

Comment: I will update the question with the expected column and values :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you could use a cumulative `COUNT` to put your data into groups, and then you can do the cumulative `SUM` of the values of both `Value` and `FixedValue` (assuming that only one can have a non-`0` value).

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT ID,
           PeriodID,
           Date,
           Value,
           FixedValue,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN FixedValue <> 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PeriodID ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp
    FROM(VALUES(1,1,CONVERT(date,'20220101'),0,0),
               (2,1,CONVERT(date,'20220102'),120,0),
               (3,3,CONVERT(date,'20221104'),60,0),
               (4,1,CONVERT(date,'20220201'),0,60),
               (5,1,CONVERT(date,'20220205'),-200,0))V(ID,PeriodID,Date,Value,FixedValue))
SELECT ID,
       PeriodId,
       Date,
       Value,
       FixedValue,
       SUM(Value + FixedValue) OVER (PARTITION BY PeriodID, Grp ORDER BY [date]) AS Balance
FROM Grps;
```